# tailing log file on windows2008 server

Tags: windows, powershell

I use the following command to tail a logfile on a w2k8 server from a windows8 client pc:

```
get-content "file" -wait
```

The log file shows up and it sits there patiently waiting for new lines to be added,
but new lines never show up when they are added.

It worked fine on w2k3 server but somehow tailing on w2k8 server does not work.

The log file is updated from a C# service:

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(logFileName, "fileListener"));
Trace.WriteLine(....)
```

Does anybody know what to do about this?

Comment: I just tried `get-content "file" -wait` on WS08. It worked. That suggests the program that is writing to "file" is behaving differently on WS08 vs W2K3. If the program writing "file" is something that you have a way to modify, I'd suggest looking at using something like FlushFileBuffers (if unmanaged code) or .NET equivalent if managed. Also you might want to look at how the program opens "file" and whether it keeps it open, or closes it between writes. If you don't have control of the program writing "file" you'd need to post more details about that program, where "file" is stored, etc.

Comment: edited in the changes

Comment: hmmm it also doesnt work locally (w8). log file gets written to but tailing never updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I repro'd the issue on my WS08 system using Trace class. I tried both Trace.Flush() and writing lots of data (100K) and neither caused get-content -wait to respond.

However I did find a workaround. You'd have to update your C# program. (While experimenting I came to the conclusion that gc -wait is pretty fragile.)

```
$twtl= new-object diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener "C:\temp\delme.trace",
                                                      "filelistener"
[diagnostics.trace]::Listeners.add($twtl)

# This sequence would result in gc -wait displaying output
[diagnostics.trace]::WriteLine("tracee messagee thingee")
[diagnostics.trace]::flush()
# Here I did file name completion such that c:\temp\delme.trace was in the 
#  completion list. 
# In other words I typed something like d and pressed tab
# And this worked every time 

# After searching for quite a while I finally found that 
#   get-itemproperty c:\temp\d*
# produced the same effect. The following sequence always worked:
# (without requiring a tab press)

[diagnostics.trace]::WriteLine("tracee messagee thingee")
[diagnostics.trace]::flush()
get-itemproperty c:\temp\d*

# To finish up
[diagnostics.trace]::Listeners.remove($twtl)
$twtl.close()
$twtl.dispose()
```

I think there's a bug somewhere. I suggest filing it on the Connect website.